# Is it common to use "gonna" in written English and even in business English?

Tags: spelling, register, contractions

*Gonna* is a short form of *going to*.

That sounds a little bit like slang. Is it common to use it in written English and even in business English?

Comment: +1 I see this a lot in the writing of Japanese people learning English!

Comment: I wouldn't use it in written business English, it's too informal but it could be used as a colloquialism in dialogue in a novel.

Comment: *Whom* is the *objective case* of who. It's not longer used in colloquial speech.

Comment: Note that *gonna* is eye dialect for a **particular contraction** of *going to*.  Even in informal text where eye dialect is appropriate, it can't be used unless it would be *natural to contract the phrase in speech*.  *"I'm gonna the store" is strange, for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Gonna" is an informal contraction of "going to". It's used in informal speech.

While informal writing is, well, *informal* (and thus the rules are loosely defined), I've never seen "gonna" in writing, except in SMSspeak. And, of course, in written dialogues in novels/etc.

So, while there's nothing stopping you from using it wherever you want, I suggest you only use it in informal writing if you want to have it in a dialogue. *Never* use it in formal English.

Comment: Quick note: gonna replace the near future tense of `going to`, not the act of actually going somewhere.  `I'm gonna be going to the store soon.`  The second cannot be replaced.

Answer (score 12):

*Gonna* is informal; you can use it in written English, but it is not normally used in business English.

Answer (score 4):

Never in writing, unless you are writing dialogue in a novel. And never in a job application!  It is slang, use it in informal speech, text messages, only with people you know.